# Can HTML <source> be used for multi CDN fallback?

Tags: html

The [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) and [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) elements support multiple [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) so the browser can select the *best* media file to render. I have a requirement for a site that the medias be hosted on multiple CDNs for redundancy and load balancing. Can I use multiple sources, one for each CDN, so the browser will automatically pick the first available?

I've experimented with the following snippet and it appears that `<video>` does fallback to another `<source>` if the first one fails, but `<picture>` doesn't (tested on Chrome 76).

```html
<html>

<body>
  <picture class='media'>
    <source srcset='https://bad-cdn.net/big_buck_bunny.jpg' />
    <source srcset='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yUQM7H4Swgw/maxresdefault.jpg' />
    <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yUQM7H4Swgw/maxresdefault.jpg' />
  </picture>
  <video class='media' controls>
      <source src='http://bad-cdn.net/big_buck_bunny.webm' />
      <source src='http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm' />
    </video>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should differentiate the two sources, by using media attribute or something.

Comment: Actually no because the sources are supposed to be equal in terms of media query; the only difference being the origin server.

Comment: I don't think it works on the basis of source url which you provide. It can check the media size or the types of media browser supports and has fallback for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should not be the way to approach this problem. Your current problem is : How do I deliver resources while maintaining enough redundancy and having a more than decent response time.

What you could try is managing yourself your own "CDN" that will act more as a load balancer that redirects to several other CDNs.

The option to use different `<source>` tag was meant to handle different formats depending on the platforms that support them.

Answer (score 1):

No because that element is to be used for selecting different media types, not different sources (though the sources for the media type can be different). Your HTML is invalid and MUST contain a media or type attribute for that very purpose.